# Raid 1 setup deleted and data gone?

Tags: partitioning, raid, mdadm

I configured a raid 1 drive setup across two 4tb hard drives a few days ago. following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04) guide. Yesterday, I wanted to configure another two drives as another raid 1, so I followed that guide again, replacing md0 with md1. Both raid setups were working fine with no problems, and I wanted to tweak my /etc/fstab setup. so I did. Upon booting this morning it was having problems recognizing my /dev/md0 raid setup, and upon booting into ubuntu, there is no longer an entry of md0 in /dev. Further, if I check gparted, I can see the two 4tb drives, but there is no raid setup shown in the drop down. If I check /proc/mdstat, yesterday it showed the two raid setups however today it only shows the one that is still working, md1.

Is there any way I can recover my raid setup? Both of the drives say there are no partitions on them so I'm worried that I may have lost all of my data (which a raid setup was supposed to avoid).

```
sudo lslbk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk  
├─sda1   8:1    0   1.8T  0 part  
└─md1    9:1    0   1.8T  0 raid1 /home/ben/Storage/md1
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk  
└─md1    9:1    0   1.8T  0 raid1 /home/ben/Storage/md1
sdc      8:32   0 447.1G  0 disk  
├─sdc1   8:33   0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
└─sdc2   8:34   0 446.6G  0 part  /
sdd      8:48   0   3.7T  0 disk  
sde      8:64   0   3.7T  0 disk  
sdf      8:80   1  57.3G  0 disk  /media/ben/30A8-C2A1
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Is this the first time you rebooted since "I wanted to tweak my /etc/fstab setup so I did"?

Comment: Please include the output of `sudo lsblk` in your question.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I had to change my /etc/fstab to mount the new raid device, and while adding that I changed mounting my /dev/md0 array with the UUID to /dev/md0. After rebooting however, my /dev/md0 no longer exists, and I cannot get the UUID as I can't see it on my system.

Comment: @vidarlo lslbk output is now up